# Human Genome, does it hold "secret/lost/inactive" Code shared with animals VIA our Common Ancestors?

Tags: science-based, biology, creature-design, hard-science, genetics

I seem to remember reading that in the human genome there's a lot of "inactive" code, codons that might have been useful millions upon millions of years ago but now have no effect on the human body as far as we can tell that's presumed to host the code needed to produce traits shown by our common ancestors (I.E hair strands growing as keratin spikes/ horns, being bipedal or a quadruped, elongated snouts etc) that we no longer display, first of all is this true or have I completely misremembered/half remembered something else? Or taken theory as fact?

Secondly, is there any evidence to suggest we could activate that part of our code and recreate these traits in humans to create a sort of Chimera?

As a follow up if reactivated would this then become hereditary?

Thank you for any responses.

Edit: In terms of world building, looking at the viability of the idea of human/animal chimera's being actually possible for potential races/ mutations for a world I'm building but the story I'm writing will have as much hard science as I can cram into it so checking the science here.

Comment: I would suggest editing this to make it more related to worldbuilding. As it stands, there isn't much connecting this question with the purpose of this site.

Comment: (1) Yes, the genome of most species contains (lots of) non-used base pairs. (2) Yes, a part of the non-used based pairs consists of broken / disactivated genes. For example, apes (including humans) carry a non-functional gene for making vitamin C. (3) Yes, sometimes these disactivated genes can be reactivated. For example, researchers at the University of Wisconsin have reactivated the [genes for making teeth in chicken](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/mutant-chicken-grows-alli/). (4) [Developmental processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Developmental_biology) are also important.

Comment: [Not entirely useful, but interesting and related](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ydqReeTV_vk).

Comment: Hello Blue.  Stack Exchange is an ask-one-specific-question/get-one-specific-answer site.  You've asked at least 3 if not 4 questions.  Please avoid doing that with future questions. (Thanks!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the science of genetics is still in its infancy, many of the assumptions of your question are simply assumptions. We actually have no idea of the purpose of "junk" DNA, or what genes are activated when, or how the expression of genes is interrelated (it does seem clear that multiple genes are activated to produce certain traits, but how these interactions happen etc. is a bit unclear at this time).

The other thing which makes this question interesting is that since we are all descended from a common ancestor, we hold many genes in common. A popular meme about this is humans and chimpanzees share almost 98% of their genes; what separates us from a chimpanzee is a vanishingly small portion of our DNA. Human beings also have a small portion of DNA from Neanderthals and Denisovians, ancient cousins to our own Ancestors (who evidently were also the original party animals).

Going back even farther, human beings also share about 50% of our genome with a banana tree, something to consider next time you eat dessert.

So it seems potentially possible to reactivate old DNA, but at the present time, I suspect we would not have any fine control over the process. Devolving feathers into the proto-feathers of dinosaurs may be possible, for example, but it may also involve expressing or suppressing other traits in unpredictable ways. Since DNA is a very "dense" storage medium, it is quite possible that you could achieve the same effects by playing with many different genes or gene combinations, making the job even harder (which combination both achieves your goal and at the same time does not induce undesirable effects on the organism).

I suspect that you would have to have a breeding pair with the same mutation (since that is what you are artificially inducing) in order for the change to breed "true", otherwise you might get the same effect as mating a horse and a donkey: a sterile mule with the desirable traits you have bred into it.

Genetic science and genetic engineering is progressing quite rapidly, so the actual answers to these questions are likely a decade or so away.

Comment: It's also useful to note the different types of genes in play. An animal has a [Hox gene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hox_gene) that says "put legs here", and so it does, but that requires genes that describe how a leg is shaped, what it's composed of, how precisely the cells generate each substance that makes it up... It's a lot more complicated that simply turning on the "elephant trunk" gene, for instance.

Comment: Although this isn't directly related to your answer or the OP, might be interested to see this https://www.genomicsengland.co.uk/the-100000-genomes-project/ My missus underwent the testing as they are trying to find out if some of the "inactive" genes cause some of the rare or unusual conditions like epilepsy or blindness etc. so they are gathering lots of people with these sorts of conditions and then comparing the genes to see if there is a common trait in the inactive genes.